# How to conditionally add a column on spreadsheet?

Tags: php, spreadsheet, xlsx

How can i add spreadsheet column conditionally, such as if the user wants to include particular column? I made this code:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A1', "SAMPLE HEADING")
        ->setCellValue('A2', "Sampling Report")
        ->setCellValue('A3', Date::PHPToExcel($dateTimeNow))
        ->setCellValue('A4', "Recipient #")
        ->setCellValue('B4', "Recipient Name")
        ->setCellValue('C4', "Date of Birth")
        ->setCellValue('D4', "Gender");
```

Now, if for example the user wants only **Recipient #** or **Recipient Name** etc. How can i achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `if` conditions and then use logic to calculate the cell position accurately.

```
    $alphas = range('A', 'Z'); //Delcare Range
    $includeRecipient = true;   // Flag to decide if Recipient # is requierd
    $includeRecipientName = false; // Flag to decide if Recipient Name is not required


    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A1', "SAMPLE HEADING")
        ->setCellValue('A2', "Sampling Report")
        ->setCellValue('A3', Date::PHPToExcel($dateTimeNow));


    $cell = '';

    if( $includeRecipient ) {
        //Can move the following block in a function
        if (empty ( $cell) ) {
            $cell = current($alphas); //Gives A if empty
        } else {
            $cell = next($alphas); //Will give next in $range
        }
        $spreadsheet->setCellValue( $cell . '4', "Recipient #")
    }

    if( $includeRecipientName ) {
        if (empty ( $cell) ) {
            $cell = current($alphas); //Gives A if empty
        } else {
            $cell = next($alphas); //Will give next value in $range
        }
        $spreadsheet->setCellValue( $cell . '4', "Recipient Name")
    }

    if (empty ( $cell) ) {
        $cell = current($alphas); //Gives A if empty
    } else {
        $cell = next($alphas); //Will give next value in $range
    }   


    $spreadsheet->setCellValue('C4', "Date of Birth")
        ->setCellValue('D4', "Gender");
```